# Expand NSViewRepresentable (NSTextView) height based on window height

Tags: swiftui, window

I created an `NSViewRepresentable` structure that manages the state of an `NSTextView`. The view, by default, only has one line and I'd like to extend that to the edge of the window.

The view is defined as such:

```swift
struct Editor: View, NSViewRepresentable {

    @Binding var text: String

    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSTextView {
        let view = NSTextView()
        view.font = NSFont.monospacedSystemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: .regular)
        return view
    }

    func updateNSView(_ view: NSTextView, context: Context) {
        let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
        view.textStorage?.setAttributedString(attributedText)
    }
}
```

[image: Current view]

It currently looks like this, it adds lines as you go. **Is there a way for the darker text area to be expanded to the bottom of the window automatically?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `NSTextView.scrollableTextView()` to do this:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State var text = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Editor(text: $text)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}

struct Editor: View, NSViewRepresentable {

    @Binding var text: String

    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSView {
        let scrollView = NSTextView.scrollableTextView()
        guard let textView = scrollView.documentView as? NSTextView else {
            return scrollView
        }
        textView.font = NSFont.monospacedSystemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: .regular)
        context.coordinator.textView = textView
        return scrollView
    }

    func updateNSView(_ view: NSView, context: Context) {
        let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
        context.coordinator.textView?.textStorage?.setAttributedString(attributedText)
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator()
    }
    
    class Coordinator {
        var textView : NSTextView?
    }
}
```